# Why does html onclick runs when it added by javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I added a navigaton bar by javascript. It made by html a href, and i want to do something on the onclick event of the href. But when it complied, it runs automaticly insted of wait for the click event.

```
function topnav() {        
    for (var i=1; i<=menuelemekdb; ++i) {
        if (menuelemek[i]['HOL_VAN']==1) {
            var li = document.createElement("li");
            var aTag=document.createElement("a");
            aTag.setAttribute('href',"#");
            aTag.id=menuelemek[i]['NEV'];
this is the line -->aTag.onclick=opensidenavigaton(menuelemek[i]['ID']);
            aTag.innerHTML=menuelemek[i]['NEV'];
            li.appendChild(aTag);
            topnavid.appendChild(li);
        }
    }
}
```

Somefunction to call

```
function opensidenavigaton(HOL_VAN) {
    alert(HOL_VAN);return false;
}
```

The topnav() function is called onload.

```
<body onload="topnav()">
    <ul class="topnav" id="topnavigaton" >
        <li class="icon">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="menuablakmeret()">&#9776;</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <iframe id="iframewindow" class="iframeclass" name="IframeWindow" src="JavaScript:''" style=""></iframe>
</body>
```

Comment: The linked question talks about `setTimeout` rather than `onclick`, but it's the same problem and the solutions there apply to this.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder deleted the comment, if I changed it to `a.addEventListener("click",function(){somefunction();});` would that have the same issue?

Comment: @Loaf: That version's good. If the function doesn't need arguments (and doesn't use any), `a.addEventListener("click", someFunction);` is sufficient. But if it needs args (like the OP's), you wrap it like that (probably passing in the element, either as an arg or as `this`).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Never knew that about params, thanks!

Comment: The solution was that:
`aTag.setAttribute("onclick",'somefunction("'+variable+'")');`